# Google picasa plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Please advice a google picasa plug that will have similar to [original](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/getEmbed) look, but with more styles or that will simply look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hands Down best one i have use is [**Picasa Express x2**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/picasa-express-x2/)

- Use Picasa user to get albums (
  username can be stored in settings )
- Show albums cover and name for get
  images.
- Images from album with caption or
  filename for selection
- Select and insert single image or
  banch for gallery.
- Enhanced Private Picasa albums after
  granting access via Google service
- WordPress MU support - sidewide
  activation, users, roles
- Gallery shortcodes for selected
  images or for get all images from
  Picasa album

**Additionaly setting is managing:**

- Image link: none, direct, Picasa
  image page, thickbox,lightbox and
  highslide with gallery
- Sorting images in dialog and in
  inserted gallery
- Caption under image or/and in
  image/link title
- Alignment for images and gallery
- Additional style or CSS classes for
  images and gallery
- Define Roles which capable to use the
  plugin
- Switch from blog to user level for
  store Picasa user and private access
  token

**And by design:**

- Support native WordPress image and
  link dialog for alignment, caption,
  description, style and CSS class
- Thumbnail images size defined in
  WordPress native properties
- Multilanguage support

Another good one would be [Picasa Albums](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/picasa-albums/) which uses the new "custom post types" feature.